# User login with permissions to routes with angular and spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, permissions, roles

I use angular 7 as frontend and spring boot as backend. I login with `LDAP` by username and password, but I have to check for the user permissions from a database (if user is enabled or disabled so he can login or not / and if the user can login check the permissions (Admin, Supervisor or User) so after login the user is navigated to the correct page. Any good advice, or a link to a good example how can I manage this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do it by using sessionStorage

sessionStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");

and by using AuthGuard you can check before navigating there you can get the value from sessionStorage like this
sessionStorage.getItem("lastname");